# W3 Total Cache "Preview mode could not be disabled"

Tags: errors, plugin-w3-total-cache

I receive the message:

> Preview mode could not be disabled. Please run chmod 777
>   /wp-content/w3-total-cache-config-preview.php to make the
>   configuration file write-able, then try again.

I have chmodded the file to 777 and the error message remains.

Comment: Please rename that file to something like `w3-total-cache-config-preview-backup.php`, then please visit `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_general`. The preview mode should have probably gone by now.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu: Thanks Pothi.  Several other errors have been removed as a result.  Add an answer and I will select it.

Comment: Glad to be of some help. I posted the answer with little explanation and use cases too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3 Total Cache plugin basically removes `w3-total-cache-config-preview.php`, when disabling the preview mode.

In `/wp-content/` folder, please check if you have a file named `w3-total-cache-config.php`.

- If it exists, please compare it with `w3-total-cache-config-preview.php` file.

  - If both have the same content, rename it to `w3-total-cache-config-preview-backup.php` and reload your site's `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_general`.
  - If both have different content, please copy all the content from `w3-total-cache-config-preview.php` to `w3-total-cache-config.php` and then rename the `preview` file.
- If it doesn't exist, please rename `w3-total-cache-config-preview.php` to `w3-total-cache-config.php` and then reload your site's `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_general`.